# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost 'is therefore not allowed access

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I want to fetch json data through URL passing. But It is showing  an error like

```
Failed to load https://sample-dec42.firebaseapp.com/one.json: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8082' is therefore not allowed access.
```

to solve this error I used the following server and controller code

controller:

```
     $http.get('https://sample-dec42.firebaseapp.com/one.json').then( function(response) {
                          $scope.resultValue = response.data;
                          console.log('successful');
                        document.write(JSON.stringify(response));
                          console.log(  $scope.resultValue);


               });
```

app.js:

```
var request = require('request');
app.use(function(req,response,next)
{
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',"*");
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type');
    next();


})
```

Here Just,I created one sample fiddle: [Click Here to View](http://jsfiddle.net/MariNithya/ADukg/16126/)

how to resolve this error. I have searched in an internet. But, still i don't have an idea why i am getting this error again and again.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: CAn you post code for your request handler?

Comment: yeah edited my post.

Comment: I mean the actual part where you return a response in your app.js.

Comment: Most likely you aren't responding with a 200 status code to the OPTIONS request.

Comment: sorry, I am not getting your point. can u check the fiddle and give a details about the issue to resolve this issue.

Comment: Just now i added one simple fiddle . In that fiddle u can see an error  in console. Another thing is when I pass the localhost as URL it will show the data. But when trying to access other domain (https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=cnbc&sortBy=top&apiKey=4d37e75dfec64065866aeb8dbb6b2344) not getting the answer. showingResponse to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8082' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: If I enable Chrome allow-access allow-origin extension it working fine. That is not correct way right?. Without enable is it possible to access the other URL@SelloMkantjwa

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

Import "cors" module to your project and if you are using Express just use it:

```
app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code::

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
// Following headers are needed for CORS
   res.setHeader('access-control-allow-headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, ajax, access-key,backend,app_request,frontend, token,device');
   res.setHeader('access-control-allow-methods', 'POST,HEAD,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS');
   res.setHeader('access-control-allow-origin', '*');
   next();
});
```

Comment: res.setHeader is different from response.header

Comment: I mean setHeader instead of header function, not the response variable. Please look before downvoting.

Comment: Sorry, i missed `header` vs `setHeader`

Comment: Now can the person remove his downvote, if the answer is helpful

Comment: Where is setHeader documented?(whoops, here it is: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value)  the express docs show using `set`, which has an alias for `header`, which would indicate that the op's code that should be doing this is correct

Comment: It is documented at https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value, also the question code should also work, but didn't has time to verify. My solution was working in my code, so I answered with that.